# exec() to assign a new value to class method scope variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
source_code = '''
def fn():
    print('source code executed')
    return 100
exec_val = fn()
'''


class Executor:

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, code):
        exec_val = 0
        exec(code)
        return exec_val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Executor.run(source_code))

>>> source code executed
>>> 0
```

The result of code above is `0` which is not what I expected `100`.
I've tried add `global exec_val` statement both in `source_code` and `Executor.run`, but still not work.

**Python 3.6.8**

Comment: I'm not sure how the class-method affects it, but `exec` always returns `None`. You need to pass it `globals()` and/or `locals()` to give the executed code access to the variable `exec_val`.

Comment: Modifications to the `locals()` dict will not necessarily be reflected in the actual local variables.